# How can i play video from full path(system location) using jsp and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, video

Hi I can't  play video file in jsp  from system location. But if i place video file(example.mp4) under web-content in  and just use the video tag in jsp with fileName like below it will get play.
 The below code didn't work

> src="C:/Users/DMS/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoView/web/video/example.mp4"

when I use the below format I can play the video

> src="video/example.mp4";  //video folder is under WEB-INF

Other problem is **When the user clicks on  (x) or clicks anywhere outside of the modal the modal closes ,But the video plays behind the modal invisibly.**
 how can i pause or close the video in background?

The complete code is below
*video.jsp*

```html
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/modal.css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hover.css" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>

<h2>Video Popup</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  
  <div id="dcont" class="dropdown-content">
        <%
        String[] arr=new String[10];
        arr[1]="C:/Users/DMS/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoView/web/video/example.mp4";
        arr[2]="video/sample.mp4";
        arr[3]="video/example.mp4";

        %> 
        <a>
       <%for(int i=1;i<4;i++){%>  
     
       <input id="myBtn<%=i%>" onclick="javascript:vidsub(this.id)" type="submit" value="<%=arr[i]%>">
      
       
       <%}%>
        </a>
  </div>
     
</div>

 
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <span class='close'>&times;</span>
      <div id="mcont"></div>      
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");   
           
            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
            function vidsub(clk) {
          
            var btn = document.getElementById(clk);
             
            var aval=btn.value;
                
            var temp=JSON.stringify(aval);
               
            document.getElementById("mcont").innerHTML =" <video autoplay id='vid' loop controls width='100%' height='100%'> <source src="+temp+" type='video/mp4'> <object data='js/video-js.swf' width='720' height='480'></object> </video>";
      
             modal.style.display = "block";
            };

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        
            span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "none";
              x.pause();
            }

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function(event) {
              if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*modal.css*

```css
/*modal.css */

body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: #666666; /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #666666;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border:none;
  width: 50%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #ff3399;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)** Using local file as element source...

> *"The below code didn't work: 
>
>   `src="C:/Users/DMS/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoView/web/video/example.mp4"`"*

Try using `file` since no `http` available on local disk:

```
src="file:///C:/Users/DMS/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoView/web/video/example.mp4"
```

**(2)** Remove video when modal is closed...

Your video is created by: `.innerHTML` method which dynamically creates a `video>` tag.

a) You could try making it blank (or empty):

```
document.getElementById("mcont").innerHTML ="";
```

b) You could try pausing the video element :

```
var myVid = document.getElementById("vid");
myVid.pause();
```

*Example code:* 
(one makes a blank `innerHTML` and other is `<video>` pause, see which method works best for you):

```
//# When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() 
{
    document.getElementById("mcont").innerHTML =""; 
    modal.style.display = "none";
    x.pause();
}

//# When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) 
{
    if (event.target == modal) 
    {
        document.getElementById("vid").pause();
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Pausing the video element works for me.. But `arr[1]="file:///C:/Users/DMS/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoView/web/video/example.mp4";` didn't works

Comment: var temp=JSON.stringify(aval); is gets value of the array but when its puts on source ....like `document.getElementById("mcont").innerHTML =" <video autoplay id='vid' loop controls width='100%' height='100%'> <source src="+temp+" type='video/mp4'> <object data='js/video-js.swf' width='720' height='480'></object> </video>";` can't play video . What is the solution?

Comment: is any solution?

Comment: Which browser are you using? For Chrome, the loading HTML file itself must also be located somewhere on the `C` drive. If HTML is online then either **(a)** User must select a video themselves through a file browse pop-up or **(b)** Use PHP to access the local file and proxy it.

Comment: I'm using firefox .And I tried `file` in other code (not inside `script`)and it works .

Comment: When I run the code directly(without IDE), it works on any browsers. But when i run the following code in netBeans IDE (using firefox as browser) video doesn't play. Is that because of mapping issue ? @VC.One